# Why have I lost functionality to highlight, add side borders, or sort by number in my spreadsheet?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel I have an existing document I have been using for for about 9 months, changing data at least weekly. Today I found I was unable to clear items highlighted in gray, but can change it to other colors.I am able to add top and bottom borders to individual cells, but cannot add side or "all" and can only address one cell in the table at a time. Furthermore, I am unable to sort by number of alpha, but am able to cut and paste. I have cut and pasted it into a new spreadsheet with no better results. I have confirmed that no conditional formatting is in place. Help?

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?

Answer (score 0):

If you know someone with excel 2016, see if you can open the file there and not experience these issues.  sometimes an update to os or office pack from microsoft can be the root cause. if you know what you are doing, check for latest updates.

I cleared a lot of issues by just upgrading to the latest office version (albeit this might be the financially last thing you might want to do -- hence try it out on someone elses pc first :-)  -- hope that helps)

x81kilo